# Update a sequlize column based on condition

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

So I want to update my table column based on the condition here is the code.

```
await CourseSubscriber.update({ 
      completion_percentage: completion_percentage,
      completed_on: **, // over here i want to check if completion_percentage<100 then update this one
    }, {
         where: {
           course_id: course_id,
           academy_id,
           user_id: user_id
    }
  })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is another solution

```
        const payload={ 
            completion_percentage: completion_percentage,
        }
        if(completion_percentage < 100){
            payload.completed_on = null
        }
        await CourseSubscriber.update(payload, {
            where: {
                course_id: course_id,
                academy_id,
                user_id: user_id
            }
        })
```

by this we only do one query to database.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to add 2 queries for update based on completion_percentage

```
if(completion_percentage < 100){
   await CourseSubscriber.update({ 
      completion_percentage: completion_percentage,
      completed_on: null,
     }, {
        where: {
          course_id: course_id,
          academy_id,
          user_id: user_id
     }
   })
} else {
   await CourseSubscriber.update({ 
      completion_percentage: completion_percentage
     }, {
        where: {
          course_id: course_id,
          academy_id,
          user_id: user_id
     }
   })
}
```